# how to delete objects in image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm relatively new to openCV, my requirement is to delete smaller island (could not attach image because of post limitation)
I have followed below code:
(1)Applied background subtraction to keep only moving objects
(2)Applied Erosion Dilation to fill the holes
(3)calculated the Average area of objects (contours)
(4)Now I want to keep only objects which is greater than Average area(Here is where i need literally help, i tried online but could not find a solution)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2 as cv
import argparse
import numpy as np

array = [None] * 100
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('--input', type=str, help='Path to a video or a sequence of image.', default='vtest.avi')
# parser.add_argument('--algo', type=str, help='Background subtraction method (KNN, MOG2).', default='MOG2')
parser.add_argument('--algo', type=str, help='Background subtraction method (KNN, MOG2).', default='KNN')
args = parser.parse_args()

# create Background Subtractor objects
if args.algo == 'MOG2':
    backSub = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
else:
    backSub = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()

capture = cv.VideoCapture("test.mp4")
if not capture.isOpened():
    print('Unable to open: ' + args.input)
    exit(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if frame is None:
        break

    # update the background model
    fgMask = backSub.apply(frame)
    # Erosion and Dilation
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.int8)
    erosion = cv.erode(fgMask, kernel, iterations=1)
    dilation = cv.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations=2)
    ## [apply]
    # contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(dilation, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print("Number of Contours = " + str(len(contours)))
    # Find max contours
    # contour = max(contours, key=len)
    '''contourImg = cv.drawContours(frame, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv.imshow("Contours", contourImg)'''

    Contour_Cnts = 0
    Total_Area_Of_all_Contour = 0
    Average_Area_Of_Contour = 0
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv.contourArea(cnt)
        Total_Area_Of_all_Contour = Total_Area_Of_all_Contour + area
        Contour_Cnts = Contour_Cnts + 1
    Average_Area_Of_Contour = Total_Area_Of_all_Contour // Contour_Cnts
    print("Number of contours", Contour_Cnts)

    Contour_Cnts = 0
    index = 0
    for cnt in contours:
        Contour_Cnts = Contour_Cnts + 1
        area = cv.contourArea(cnt)
        if area > Average_Area_Of_Contour:
            index = int(index) + 1
            # array[index] = contours[Contour_Cnts]
    # cv.drawContours(frame, array, -1, (0,0,255), 2)

    cv.imshow('Frame', frame)
    cv.imshow('FG Mask', fgMask)
    cv.imshow('Dilation', dilation)

capture.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: either use `connectedComponents(WithStats)`, derive a mask from the labels map for whatever component you want to erase... or use drawContours to derive the same mask... and then use the mask to erase that area in the picture. I'm sure you can figure out the parts of all that.